# Sort Alphabetically JS Loop with Fetched Data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

i have a program that gets data from 2 fetched URLs, with CSS I automatically create a Business Card type design and it does that automatically in a 'for' loop.
Now I need to create a Sort Alphabetical button by that "${users[count].name}  and I do not have any idea how to do that.

```
Promise.all([
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos'),
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
]).then(function (responses) {
    return Promise.all(responses.map(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    }));
}).then(([ photos , users]) =>{
    var names = document.getElementById('names')
    for (let count = 0; count < 10; count++){
        names.innerHTML+=`
        <div class= "profile_card">
        <div class=topCont>
            <img class="thumbnail" src="${photos[count].thumbnailUrl}">
           
            <div class="personal">
            
                        <h2 class="name">${users[count].name}</h5>
... etc
</div>   </div>                      
            `
```

After this i have some EventListeners but I do not this they matter. The idea is that i need to be able to sort these data that I print but I do not know how to store all of them in an Array and after that I thought about using a 'for' loop from 0 to 10 to output them by the number that resulted to be the lowest or something like that.

Comment: See [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value?rq=1).

Comment: You will need to redo the templating when that button is clicked, so that loop probably needs to go into a function. And your arrays need to be stored within that function's scope.

Comment: @ITgoldman ok, i understand that and I've tried that. But how do I change my code to be able to print them that way. I have written a code with a function compare but how do I do it to be able to have the arranged in that way

Answer (score 0):

Split your logic into functions.

```js
var arr_photos;
var arr_users;

Promise.all([
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos'),
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
]).then(function(responses) {
  return Promise.all(responses.map(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }));
}).then(([photos, users]) => {
  arr_photos = photos; 
  arr_users = users;
  do_output(arr_photos, arr_users)
})


function do_sort() {
  arr_users.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.name > b.name) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.name < b.name) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0
  })
}

function do_output() {
  photos = arr_photos
  users = arr_users;

  var names = document.getElementById('names')
  names.innerHTML = '';
  for (let count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
    names.innerHTML += `<div class="profile_card">
        <div class="topCont">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="${photos[count].thumbnailUrl}">
            <div class="personal">
            <h2 class="name">${users[count].name}</h2>
        </div>   </div>   </div>`
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="do_sort(); do_output()">sort</button>
<div id="names"></div>
```

Comment: Omg man, thank you so so much. It works perfectly. I created another function like the do_sort one for the Z-A Order and everything works fine. What I wanted to ask you is if i create another button with the onclick function do_output();  why won't it revert it back to default. In the console i get some result but it does not change the printed results.

Answer (score 0):

You should store your responses into array and then manipulate them to sort the data.

```js
const loadDataButton = document.getElementById('loadDataButton')
const sortByUserName = document.getElementById('sortByUserName')
const sortByAlbumName = document.getElementById('sortByAlbumName')

let users = []
let albums = []

loadDataButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => users = data)
  
  await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    albums = data.map(x => ({...x, user: users.find(user => user.id === x.userId)}))
  })
 
  showAlbums()
})


function showAlbums(){
  const app = document.getElementById('app')
  
  app.innerHTML = '' //clear
  
  albums.forEach(album => {
    const p = document.createElement('p')
    p.innerHTML = `${album.title} - ${album.user.name}`
    app.appendChild(p)
  }) 
}


sortByUserName.addEventListener('click', () => {
  albums.sort((a, b) => {
    if(a.user.name > b.user.name) return 1
    else return -1
  })
  
  showAlbums()
})

sortByAlbumName.addEventListener('click', () => {
  albums.sort((a, b) => {
    if(a.title > b.title) return 1
    else return -1
  })
  
  showAlbums()
})
```

```html
<button id="loadDataButton">Load data</button>

<button id="sortByUserName">Sort by user name</button>
<button id="sortByAlbumName">Sort by album name</button>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    sort.addEventListener("change",(e)=>{
    let copyArrClone = [...copyArrr];
    if (e.target.value == 'az') {
        let sortAz = copyArrClone.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
        filteredArr = sortAz;
        getDataJson();
    } else if (e.target.value == 'za') {
        let sortZa = copyArrClone.sort((a, b) => b.title.localeCompare(a.title));
        filteredArr = sortZa;
        getDataJson();
    } else {
        getDataJson();
    }
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!